# JavaScript дерево каталогов, как на Github

Tags: javascript, плагин

Приветствую Вас, участники сообщества.

Однажды где-то мне попадался плагин, для отображения директорий/файлов как на гитхабе. Сегодня этот плагин пригодился, а найти не могу. пичалька=\ Можете помочь в этом деле?

Answer (score 1):

- [JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/)
- [DHTMLXTree](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/)
- [dynatree](https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/)

Comment: Это все здорово, нужен filemanager в MAC стиле. как на гитхабе.